# Gem for time manipulation similar to ActiveSupport helper

Tags: ruby, date, time

Is there a gem that simplifies date and time manipulation like ActiveSupport? Like adding a month to a time, returning the beginning of the current month etc.

I have a simple ruby project that needs time calculations but I want to avoid to include that gem because it does way more than just time calculation.

Comment: You can load just the active support date extensions: `require 'active_support/core_ext/date'`.

Comment: Thanks, I know but I would rather not have a dependency on ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like the `chronic` gem?

https://github.com/mojombo/chronic ?

Comment: I think that chronic is more for parsing than for Time arithmetics.

Comment: You're right... In this case, why don't you take @ZachKemp 's idea of using `active_support`,  extract the files in a separate gem, and make use of it? https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext ; `check the date_time` , `date` and `date_and_time` directories

Comment: This is a solution that I was thinking about, but I was hoping there was already a gem for that. If I don't find that gem, I will probably create one.

Comment: Cool :-) (The only reason I'm keeping my answer is because other people might land on this page and find `chronic` useful for their purposes)

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I was also searching for a gem to facilitate time arithmetic because I also did not want to add ActiveSupport as a runtime dependency of the gem I am currently developing.

[TimeMath](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_math2) is a small and dependency-free gem that makes it really easy to do time calculations.

Using TimeMath, this is how you get the beginning of the current month (as of version 0.0.5):

```
TimeMath.month.floor(Time.now)
```